# Return "bad request" but need "not found"

Tags: spring-boot

here my custom handler exception:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ProductNotFoundException extends RuntimeException
{
    public ProductNotFoundException(String exception) {
        super(exception);
    }
}
```

So when throw `ProductNotFoundException` then response status must be **404**. Because I add annotation:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

here controller:

```
 import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@PutMapping("/product")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(@RequestBody String payload) {
        Product product = getProduct(payload);
        Optional<Product> findProduct = productRepository.findById(product.getId());
        if (findProduct.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Product>(updateProduct, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            String error = "Not found product with id = " + product.getId();
            throw new ProductNotFoundException(error);
        }
    }
```

As you can see if product not found I throw my custom exception: `ProductNotFoundException`

But when I send put request with not exist product's id here http response:

```
{
  "message": "Not found product with id = 123"
}
// PUT http://127.0.0.1:9090/api/v1/product
// HTTP/1.1 400 
// Content-Type: application/json
// Transfer-Encoding: chunked
// Date: Wed, 09 Sep 2020 16:21:22 GMT
// Connection: close
// Request duration: 0.138291s
```

The question is: Why http status is **400** ?
It must be **404**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @RestControllerAdvice or @ControllerAdvice to properly handle exceptions with http status.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class WebRestControllerAdvice {
  
  @ExceptionHandler(CustomNotFoundException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  public ResponseMsg handleNotFoundException(Throwable ex) {
    ResponseMsg responseMsg = new ResponseMsg(ex.getMessage());
    return responseMsg;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also you can use any other more specific Custom Class instead of ResponseMsg.

Answer (score 0):

Http Status 400 means it is a bad request. I am not sure what you are using to test this, `Swagger` or `postman` or something else. And also i am not sure how you are preparing your input.

Try removing your `content-type` header and see if that works.

Comment: Remove content- type, but it not help. Same result - 400. But I need 404

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type parameter of your return to be a generic wildcard (`<?>`) would allow you to use the following code in order to return any status that you like instead of throwing an exception while including a meaningful error message as a String - you currently *cannot* do this as you have declared you will always be returning a `Product` body type.

```java
else {
    String error = "Not found product with id = " + product.getId();
    return ResponseEntity
        .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
        .body(error);
}
```

In your return for a successful PUT operation you're also referencing a variable that doesn't not exist (`updateProduct`) which would be returned in a header. I would assume here that you would rather set the body to be of type `Product` referencing the value of the established present `Optional` parameter. This can be achieved using something like this:

```java
return new ResponseEntity.ok(findProduct.get());
```